# How can Joule-Thomson inversion coefficient of ideal gas be zero? Does temperature of ideal gas not change on adiabatic expansion?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ideal-gas

Does Joule-Thomson coefficient being zero means there will be no change in temperature?
 If that is the case then according to first law of thermodynamics, E = Q+W (don't know how to add delta sign). So, if expansion takes place in adiabatic conditions, the gas must cooldown.
I am confused, any explanations of the Joule-Thomson effect would be appreciated.

Comment: J-T E is not an ordinary AB expansion. The gas does not do any work  expanding against external pressure there. At ordinary adiabatic expansion, all gases cool down.

Comment: `$\Delta U = Q + W$`  ->  $\Delta U = Q + W$

Comment: Expression formatting reference:
 [Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)/[CH+Math expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)/[Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)/[Math tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)/[Advanced](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know)

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks, I think I understand now. The textbook I was studying from began the discussion on J-T-E using adiabatic expansion, that got stuck in my head.

Comment: @Poutnik Just to be clear, when an ideal gas is taken from a region of very high pressure to a region of very low pressure suddenly, it will not cool down or heat up because the gas doesn't do any work against external pressure. Is that right?

Comment: It depends on omitted details in the mentioned scenario. If the ideal gas was in an isolated balloon, lifted 1 km in the atmosphere it would cool down. If it expanded against vacuum between 2 chambers in isolated, constant volume system, it's temperature would remain.

Comment: @Poutnik I get it. Thanks.